# Bootstrap navigationbar Active State not working in my theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the active class to work with my Bootstrap navbar but it's not working (I'm assuming because I've made too many CSS changes to the nav class).

```
  <!-- StyleSheets Files -->

    <link href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>/styles/styles.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>/styles/default.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>../styles/bjqs.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>/css/menu.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>/css/bootstrap.css" media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/> 



    <!-- JavaScript Files -->

    <script src="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>/scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>/scripts/zebra_datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>../scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>../scripts/bjqs-1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
   <script>

  $(".navbar-nav a").on("click", function(){

    $(".navbar-nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
 });
     </script>
```

CSS

```
        .navbar {
        border-radius: 0;
        float:left;
    }

    .navbar-new {
        background-color: #333;
        border-color: #393939;
    }

    .navbar-new .navbar-brand,
    .navbar-new .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-new .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #FFF;
    }

    .navbar-new .navbar-nav > li > a {
        color: #FFF;
    }

    .navbar-new .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-new .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
        background-color: #337ab7;

    }

    .navbar-new .navbar-nav > .active > a,
    .navbar-new .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-new .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {

        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #337ab7;

    }

    .navbar-new .navbar-text {
        color: #FFF;
    }

    .navbar-new .navbar-toggle {
        border-color: #337ab7;
    }

    .navbar-new .navbar-toggle:hover,
    .navbar-new .navbar-toggle:focus {
        background-color: #337ab7;

    }

    .navbar-new .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
```

Here is the screenshot, what outcome comes right now!

Image of Navigation Bar -

[image: Navigation Bar Image]

Here is the HTML , i have added on header

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-new" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- logo -->

        <!-- menu -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/products.php">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/products.php?type=top">Top Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/products.php?type=new">New Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/shopping_cart.php">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/check_out.php">Check Out</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>contactus.php">Deals</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>contactus.php">Sale</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>contactus.php">Contact US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you post a JS Fiddle please?

Comment: Here is a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoRQey/). It works just fine. Perhaps you're not loading the JavaScript below the jQuery.

Comment: its works fine on pen! can you explain! which files are not loading fine. bit confused! i have added links on my first post. can you check paths! which files probably are not loading fine

Answer (score 0):

Ali,

I agree with Tania. It's working fine.
Mean while try to check whether you are loading bootstrap version **3.3.6 or below**, rather than **4.0.0(alpha**). Because i tried with both versions. Its not working fine with alpha version.

Comment: i am running bootstrap-3.3.6-dist version!

Comment: It should be loading Jquery-2.1.4.  Then bootstrap-3.3.6 css and bootstrap-3.3.6 js file. And write your css code. And at last your script file. It could do better.

Comment: i have tried, no effect, i have placed my links above, can you check yourself sequence! and send me